# Why I getContextualVersionConflict error when I am importing web3

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, web3py

code:
!pip install web3
!pip install --force-reinstall jsonschema==3.2.0
from web3 import Web3

In colab

```
from web3 import Web3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ContextualVersionConflict                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-22-bd73e069b4e9> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from web3 import Web3

5 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in _resolve_dist(self, req, best, replace_conflicting, env, installer, required_by, to_activate)
    871             # Oops, the "best" so far conflicts with a dependency
    872             dependent_req = required_by[req]
--> 873             raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    874         return dist
    875 

ContextualVersionConflict: (protobuf 3.20.3 (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('protobuf>=4.21.6'), {'web3'})
```

Comment: Will you please [edit] your question to show a small code example that produces this error?

Answer (score 0):

I used a different version of web3 5.28.0 to be specific and after
"!pip install --force-reinstall jsonschema==3.2.0" you must restart the runtime in colab to make "from web3 import Web3" work